# Matlab, Basics about Loops

Tags: matlab, loops

I need to ask the user for a temperature, k or K stands for kelvin, c or C stands for celsius and f or F stands for Fahrenheit. How can I put all of those in a loop? I need to keep asking the user until they enter in one of the letters above. This is what I have so far.

```
  tempType = input('What type of temperature would you like to use: ', 's');

  value = ['k','K','c','C','f','F'];

  while strcmp(tempType, value) == 1  

     tempType = input('What type of temperature would you like to use: ', 's');

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather do like this to avoid two exactly same lines (tested in R2011b):

```
AllowedTemperature = {'k','K','c','C','f','F'};
SelectedTemperature = '';
while ~any(strcmp(SelectedTemperature,AllowedTemperature))
    SelectedTemperature = input('What type of temperature would you like to use: ', 's');
end
disp( [ 'SelectedTemperature: ' SelectedTemperature ] )
```

Comment: `~any(strcmp(....))` could be replaced by `~ismember(SelectedTemperature, AllowedTemperature)`

Answer (score 0):

You want `(length(tempType)~=1 || length(findstr(tempType,value))==0)` to be the condition of your while